# Many dom elements. Performance AngularJS vs Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, performance-testing

We have a problem with performance that it related to a Grid with a lot of elements. Worst case(very rare) it is up to 10000 DOM elements connected to angularJS but a more normal case is around 1000-2000.

I have done some testing on performance and it turns our that the performance is very similar both in angularJS and angular. I was a bit suprised because the performance is said to be one of the reasons to upgrade to angular.

The meaturement was on the first load, painting and connecting elements to the grid. When then changing elements angular was a little faster but it was not a 
big one.

I mixed quite a lot back and forth but the code looks something like this:

Why is not Angular faster? Is the bottle neck in this case in the DOM?
Is there another way to make it faster except paging and eternal scroll?

**AngularJS:**
HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    Angular 1
    <span ng-click="loadData(1000)" style "height:500px; width:200px; background-color:green">{{title}}</span>

    <span ng-click="resetData()" style "height:500px; width:200px; background-color:green"> - Reset</span>
    <!-- <table class="table table-hover table-condensed bs-body-table" infinite-scroll="myPagingFunction()" infinite-scroll-distance="3"> -->
    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed bs-body-table">
        <tbody>
            <!-- Level 1 Groups -->
            <tr ng-repeat="row in reportList track by $index">
                <td>{{::row.column1}}</td>
                <td>{{::row.column2}}</td>
                <td>{{::row.column3}}</td>
                <td>{{::row.column4}}</td>
                <td>{{::row.column5}}</td>
                <td>{{::row.column6}}</td>
                <td>{{::row.column7}}</td>
                <td>{{::row.column8}}</td>
                <td>{{::row.column9}}</td>
                <td>{{::row.column10}}</td>
                <td>{{::row.column11}}</td>
                <td>{{::row.column12}}</td>
                <td>{{::row.column13}}</td>
                <td>{{::row.column14}}</td>
                <td>{{::row.column15}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
controller() {
    var data = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        data.push({
            id: i,
            column1: 'column1' + i,
            column2: 'column2' + i,
            column3: 'column3' + i,
            column4: 'column4' + i,
            column5: 'column5' + i,
            column6: 'column6' + i,
            column7: 'column7' + i,
            column8: 'column8' + i,
            column9: 'column9' + i,
            column10: 'column3' + i,
            column11: 'column11' + i,
            column12: 'column12' + i,
            column13: 'column13' + i,
            column14: 'column14' + i,
            column15: 'column15' + i,
        });
    };
}
```

**Angular:**

Html:

```
<span (click)="loadData()">{{buttonText}}</span>
<span (click)="resetData()">Reset</span>
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of reportList; trackBy: let i=index">
        <td>{{row.column1}}</td>
        <td>{{row.column2}}</td>
        <td>{{row.column3}}</td>
        <td>{{row.column4}}</td>
        <td>{{row.column5}}</td>
        <td>{{row.column6}}</td>
        <td>{{row.column7}}</td>
        <td>{{row.column8}}</td>
        <td>{{row.column9}}</td>
        <td>{{row.column10}}</td>
        <td>{{row.column11}}</td>
        <td>{{row.column12}}</td>
        <td>{{row.column13}}</td>
        <td>{{row.column14}}</td>
        <td>{{row.column15}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Typescript:

```
  public loadData() {
    this.buttonText += '!';
    this._ngZone.run(() => {
      this.reportList = this.data;
    });
  }

  public resetData() {
    this.buttonText += '!';
    this.reportList = new Array();
  }

  public calcData() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      this.data.push(<Item>{id: i,
        column1: 'column1' + i,
        column2: 'column2' + i,
        column3: 'column3' + i,
        column4: 'column4' + i,
        column5: 'column5' + i,
        column6: 'column6' + i,
        column7: 'column7' + i,
        column8: 'column8' + i,
        column9: 'column9' + i,
        column10: 'column3' + i,
        column11: 'column11' + i,
        column12: 'column12' + i,
        column13: 'column13' + i,
        column14: 'column14' + i,
        column15: 'column15' + i,
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: (tl;dr) your AngularJS example has **one-way data-binding** with `{{:: __ }}` syntax (equivalent to `ng-bind`), which removes watchers unlike with `{{ __ }}` / `ng-model` and therefore making it faster. I'm not familiar with Angular, but perhaps you need a one-way data-binding in there as well

Comment: I have tried without and it gave the the same time. I was a little surprised about that.

Comment: It's unclear whether you use AOT or not. It's unclear what was measurement method. Those two examples aren't equivalent, and they aren't complete. The whole thing is a little bit pointless. The question is already not in its best shape, but consider providing a way to replicate your measurements at least. The big deal about Angular performance is OnPush change detection strategy, but it wasn't used here.

Comment: Why would you create that many html elements, most of them won't even be visible to the user unless they scroll to it? Can you implement something like [polymer iron list](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-list) and only create/load the elements that are actually visible?

Comment: You can't expect that initial *10000 DOM elements* rendering will be any fast, there's not much to improve. While redrawing may make a difference, and this includes asynchronous grid population.